# Multi select on same database with different conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

i have pagination and i should call database for two times!
it's meant i should call :

> SELECT COUNT(users_id) FROM users

for get all of database rowCount 
and in another database fetch i have :

> SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY users_id ASC LIMIT 1, 2

for create pagination 
is there anyway to create one database call and get the same results ? 
i try this:

> SELECT COUNT(users_id),* FROM users ORDER BY users_id ASC LIMIT 1, 2

but this, call just 2 (count users_id) and broke pagination :(

Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this with 2 Queries:

1) first get your result with LIMIT and OPTION **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS**

2) get the num rows without LIMIT

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.* FROM yourTable 1 LIMIT 2;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.* FROM yourTable t LIMIT 2;
+-----+------------+
| id  | toDate     |
+-----+------------+
| 111 | 2017-03-02 |
| 111 | 2017-03-20 |
+-----+------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
+--------------+
| FOUND_ROWS() |
+--------------+
|            4 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: it's true but how can i get FOUND_ROWS ? , like $row["users_id"]

Comment: thanks alot it's work and my problem solved :* :* :* :* :***************

Comment: $total = $db_con->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible because it returns different result sets - first query returns single-column result with an int, the other query returns all columns from users.

You need to do two separate queries for this.